# (ORA-02270: no hay ninguna clave única o primaria correspondiente para esta lista de columnas)

Tags: oracle

Ejecute el siguiente código en una base de datos ORACLE y obtengo el error

> (ORA-02270: no hay ninguna clave única o primaria correspondiente para esta lista de columnas)

```
create table Libro(
  idLibro number(20) not null,
  Titulo varchar2(30) not null,
  Editorial varchar2(30) not null,
  Area varchar2(30)
);


create table Autor(
  idAutor number(20) not null,
  Nombre varchar2(30) not null,
  Nacionalidad varchar2(30)
);

create table LibAut(
  idAutor number(20) not null,
  idLibro number(20) not null,
  foreign key(idAutor) references Autor(idAutor),
  foreign key(idLibro) references Libro(idLibro),
  primary key(idAutor, idLibro)
);
```

El problema ocurre en el momento de crear la tabla `LibAut`.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo tratas de vincular las tablas por medio de sus llaves primarias hacia la tabla `LibAut` por lo que en las primeras 2 los `id` deberían estar declarados como `PRIMARY KEY`

```
create table Libro(
idLibro number(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Titulo varchar2(30) not null,
Editorial varchar2(30) not null,
Area varchar2(30));


create table Autor(
idAutor number(20) PRIMARY KEY,
Nombre varchar2(30) not null,
Nacionalidad varchar2(30));
```

Por otro lado en tu última tabla, donde la relacionas con las tablas anteriores; tu declaración debería ser así

```
create table LibAut(
idAutor number(20) not null,
idLibro number(20) not null,
constraint fk_LibAut_Autor foreign key(idAutor) references Autor(idAutor),
constraint fk_LibAut_Libro foreign key(idLibro) references Libro(idLibro)
);
```

**ACLARACIONES**

1. Usando al inicio de la declaración `CONSTRAINT` hacemos referencia a una restricción
2. posterior se asigna un nombre de este tipo `fk_tablaDestino_TablaOrigen` **(es decir a cada foreign key le debes asignar un nombre con lo cual se identifica)** cosa que en tu código original no estaba puesto
3. En las primera dos tablas que es con las que tratas de establecer la relación o vinculación, los campos que usarás deberían tener declarado el atributo `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.....

Comment: Te sirvió? @Oliver

Comment: Si te sirvió puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta y votarla. Así das retroalimnetación al que te contestó y a los que visiten después tu pregunta (porque obtengan el mismo error y el navegador los lleve hasta ahí)